# Поиск файлов, созданных в нерабочее время

Tags: c++

Написать программу, которая находит фаайлы, созданные в нерабочее время.

Понятия не имею, как такое сделать. Знаю, как искать файлы, но в нерабочее время - понятия не имею, как...

Наверное, файлы, которые были созданы, пока за компьютером никого не было. Кто-нибудь может помочь?

Comment: А если человек написал скрипт, который создает файлы, и оставил его выполняться на ночь?

Comment: 1. Вам для какой ОС ?

2. Уточните, что такое нерабочее время ? Оно для всех одинаковое ?

Вообще в \*nix утилитой find можно найти файлы модифицированные в заданном интервале времени.

Comment: Нужно для винды, нерабочее время - это, например, работа человека с 10 и до 6 часов. 8-часовой рабочий день можно еще назвать. Вот чтобы находило с 18 и до 10 часов утра.

Comment: Нужно разобраться с тем, как определять время создания файла.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#include <locale.h> 
#include <malloc.h> 
#include <io.h> 
#include <time.h>

#define HOUR_START  16
#define HOUR_FINISH 10

void listdir(char *root) { 
    _finddata_t fd; 
    int rc; 
    long hFile; 
    char mask[260]; 
    char subdir[260]; 
    struct tm *ti;

    sprintf(mask, "%s\\*.*", root); 
    for( rc = (hFile = _findfirst(mask, &fd)); rc != -1; rc = _findnext(hFile, &fd) ) { 
        if ( fd.name[0] != '.' ) { 
            if ( fd.attrib & _A_SUBDIR ) { 
                sprintf(subdir, "%s\\%s", root, fd.name); 
                listdir(subdir); 
            } 
            else {
                ti = localtime (&(fd.time_create));
                if ( (ti->tm_hour >= HOUR_START) || (ti->tm_hour < HOUR_FINISH) )
                    printf("\n%s\\%s %02d:%02d:%02d", root, fd.name, ti->tm_hour, ti->tm_min, ti->tm_sec); 
            }
        } 
    } 
}

int main() { 
    char root[260] = "c:\\temp";

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    listdir(root); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Спасибище!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Если сами хотите на Си писать, то посмотрите вызов stat()

```
#include <sys/stat.h> // не получается ввести этот текст по ходу ответа
```

Из него время модификации файла можно взять. Как обходить все (или заданные) файлы Вы сказали знаете.

Comment: Сам не хочу)) Библиотека вообще не знакомая... Вот нашел пример, но он не до конца подходит: [Поиск файла по шаблону](http://www.cyberforum.ru/visual-cpp/thread347192.html#post1954164)

В с++ не силен, поэтому прошу объяснить, как вообще с этой либой работать.